# Can you change Shared Preferences from outside your app?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is there a way user could mess with the shared preferences values without the help of my app? E.g. can I store license details here and not worry about user extracting and copying the license key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its really easy to access the shared preferences. 
All you need is a file explorer with root access, they are saved in an xml file in `/data/data/YOUR_APP_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_APP_NAME_preferences.xml`

For licencing you should either use google play's licence check or implement your own checking on a remote server.

Answer (score 2):

If the context of the shared preferences are private (you define it when you create) only with root access it is possible to access them, without being the application who created.

Comment: With root access you can read and write as long as you know the memory location. It is not completely straightforward though.

Comment: @BasvanStein there are apps that help in that process like CheatDroid... it is not difficult to do that.

Comment: Yes I know, but still, usually these apps use the fact that the value is changing or that you know the value (partly), if that is not the case it is much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Shared preferences are stored inside the app's space, when you uninstall the app, the preferences are also gone.

So normally users cannot get these values, they are stored privately.

However, with root access and a simple memory search app, a user could be able to access the data. (It is always better to store such things server side.)